# Why $G/F(G)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\mathrm{Out}(F(G))$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, automorphism-group

I know two facts and I’ve managed to figure out how to prove one, but the other one is still a little confusing.

> Let $G$ be a finite solvable group and $F(G)$ is the Fitting subgroup of $G$.
>
> (1) $G/Z(F(G))$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of ${\rm Aut}(F(G))$;
>
> (2) $G/F(G)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of ${\rm Out}(F(G))$.

Proof of (1):

$F(G)$ is normal in $G$, so $G=N_G(F(G))$. Since $G$ is solvable, $Z(F(G))=C_G(F(G))$. $F(G)$ is a characteristic subgroup of $G$ and $Z(F(G))$ is a characteristic subgroup of $F(G)$, therefore $Z(F(G))$ is characteristic and normal in $G$, and $G/Z(F(G))$ is hence well-defined. By the $N/C$ theorem, $G/Z(F(G))=N_G(F(G))/C_G(F(G))$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of ${\rm Aut}(F(G))$.

About (2), I asked a question and have got some ideas.

I know that $F(G)/Z(F(G))\cong {\rm Inn}(F(G))$ and by (1) that $G/Z(F(G))$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of ${\rm Aut}(F(G))$.

So by the third isomorphism theorem, we have $G/F(G) \cong G/Z(F(G)) \big/ F(G)/Z(F(G))$.

**If it is true that, say, “if $A\cong M$ and $B\cong N$ where $B\trianglelefteq A$ and $N\trianglelefteq M$ then $A/B\cong M/N$”, then we’re done. However, it is not true in general.  I believe that I ignored something important. So what should I do next? It really seems very close. It’s quite obvious to think in an intuitive way that $G/F(G)\cong G/Z(F(G)\big/ F(G)/Z(F(G))$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of ${\rm Aut}(G)/{\rm Inn}(G)$ since the $G/Z(F(G))$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of ${\rm Aut}(G)$ and $F(G)/Z(F(G))\cong {\rm Inn}(G)$. But it’s not sufficient in a proof. I think there’s still something missing.**

**Let me just make my question clear.** I want to take an example. Assume that $A$ is a subgroup of $C$ and $B\trianglelefteq A$. Also, assume that $N\trianglelefteq M$. If $A\cong M$ and $B\cong N$, then it is Not true in general that $A/B\cong M/N$. So in the case that we were talking about, $C={\rm Aut}(F(G))$, $B={\rm Inn}(F(G))$, $M=G/Z(F(G))$, $N=F/Z(F(G))$, it’s just the same: $M$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $C$, namely $A$, and $N\cong B$. But we don’t have $A/B\cong M/N$ in general. I want to know how to prove it in this specific case.

Any help is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: It is most definitely not true that $A\cong M$ and $B\cong N$ imply $A/B\cong M/N$. That's false in general. I already gave you an example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3655370/a-question-about-the-quotient-group-of-images#comment7511960_3655370).

Comment: Your "let me just make my question clear" is [a repeat of your own question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3655370/a-question-about-the-quotient-group-of-images#comment7511960_3655370) **Don't do that!**

Comment: Posted near-simulatenously on math.overflow. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/359161/why-g-fg-is-isomorphic-to-a-subgroup-of-rm-outfg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $F(G)$ is normal in $G$, $G$  acts by conjugation on $F(G)$. This gives you a map $G\to \mathrm{Aut}(G)$. The kernel of this map is $C_G(F(G))=Z(F(G))$ as you note, so the map factors to an embedding $G/Z(F(G))\to \mathrm{Aut}(G)$.

Now, the image of $F(G)$ under this embedding, is the image of $F/Z(F(G))$ under the map that sends an element to the conjugation map by that element; this **is** the group of inner automorphisms of $F(G)$ (not just "isomorphic to it", but **exactly** it), so 
$$\frac{G/Z(F(G))}{F(G)/Z(F(G))} \cong \frac{G}{F(G)}$$
embeds into $\mathrm{Aut}(G)/\mathrm{Inn}(F(G)) = \mathrm{Out}(F(G))$. 
That is all you need.

Comment: Thanks. It seems very clear now. But I still have a question. Denote the embedding by $\phi$. I now know that ${\rm Inn}(F(G))=\phi(F(G))\trianglelefteq \phi(G)=:A \le {\rm Aut}(F(G))$. But how can we conclude that $\phi(G)/\phi(F(G))\cong A/{\rm Inn}(F(G))$? Because it is not true in general, for an arbitrary embedding $\phi$, that if $\phi(G)=A, \phi(K)=B$ then $\phi(G)/\phi(K)\cong A/B$. There’s still something on the way, I think, for example if we show that ${\rm Inn}(F(G))$ is a subgroup of ${\rm Aut}(F(G))$ of an unique order then we’re done. Please tell me if it doesn’t make sense.

Comment: @Hello: And so you insist on trying to invoke a “theorem” that doesn’t exist, when you don’t need it. $\phi$ sends $F(G)$ to $\mathrm{Inn}(F(G))$. It’s **not** an isomorphism, it’s an **equality**. $\phi(F(G))$ is not just “isomorphic” to $\mathrm{Inn}(F(G))$, it is **equal** to $\mathrm{Inn}(F(G))$. So $\phi(G)/\phi(F(G)) = \phi(G)/\mathrm{Inn}(F(G))\leq \mathrm{Aut}(F(G))/\mathrm{Inn}(F(G))$.

Comment: Thanks! I get it now. I was not trying to get a “theorem” or something, I was just stuck. Now with “$G/F(G))\cong \phi(G)/\phi(F(G)) = \phi(G)/\mathrm{Inn}(F(G))\leq \mathrm{Aut}(F(G))/\mathrm{Inn}(F(G))$” I’ve understood it. Thanks for your kind answer and comments. Thank you!

Comment: @Hello: you were trying to use a nonexistent result that $\mathrm{Inn}(F(G))$ is the only subgroup of that order in $\mathrm{Aut}(F(G))$... even though I had already stated what I state in the comment above, in the original post: “this **is** the group of inner automorphisms of $F(G)$”.

Comment: I thought it was not sufficient to get to the conclusion, which it was, so I took an example to ask if there was something that I missed. It’s just an example! I didn’t really want to prove that ${\rm Inn}(F(G))$ has unique order. It’s just an example of anything that could help me push forward. Since now I know it’ sufficient, I don’t need that kind of things anymore. I don’t live in an English-speaking country, maybe I just didn’t express my thoughts clearly. It’s very nice of you to be so patient. Many thanks to you!